# Scala: return reference to a function

Tags: scala

I'd like to have a Scala functions that returns the reference to another function, is that possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can return a function type (this is defined by `A => B`).  In this case Int to Int:

```
scala> def f(x:Int): Int => Int =  { n:Int => x + n }
f: (x: Int)(Int) => Int
```

When you call the function you get a new function.

```
scala> f(2)
res1: (Int) => Int = <function1>
```

Which can be called as a normal function:

```
scala> res1(3)
res2: Int = 5
```

Answer (score 7):

One way (somewhat unique to functional object-orientation) you can use higher order functions is to create loose couplings between objects.

In the example below the class `Alarm` has a method `check4Danger()` that checks if a calculated value exceeds the `DangerLevel`. The Alarm class does not know anything about the objects that call it.

The `Car` class has a method `engineCrashRisk()` that returns an anonymous function that calculate the risk of engine crash. `Car` does not have dependency to Alarm.

```
case class Alarm(temperature: Double, pressure: Double){
  val DangerLevel = 100000.0
  def check4Danger( f: (Double, Double) => Double): Boolean = {
    val risk = f(temperature, pressure)
    if( risk > DangerLevel ){
      println("DANGER: "+ risk )
      true
    }else{
      println("Safe: " + risk)
      false
    }
  }
}

case class Car(fuelRate: Double, milage: Int){
  def engineCrashRisk() =
    (temperature: Double, pressure: Double) =>
      temperature * milage + 2*pressure / fuelRate
}


val car = Car(0.29, 123)
val riskFunc = car.engineCrashRisk

val alarm = Alarm(124, 243)
val risk = alarm.check4Danger(riskFunc)
```

The output of this script is:

```
Safe: 16927.862068965518
```

In this example we used anonymous functions with closures to create a dependency free method call between the `Alarm` and `Car` objects. Does this example make any sense?

Comment: +1,Offtopic aside: Please change `DANGER_LEVEL` to `DangerLevel`. Odersky book recommends use of PascalCase for constants.

Comment: @Rahuλ No shit! This recommendation feels totally unorthodox, but who am I to question the will of our great leader :-)