# Writing a Scala function that returns a function when invoked

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Assuming a typical hash function for a value `x` :

```
h(x) = ( a * x + b ) % R
```

I want to write a scala function say `buildHashFunction` that returns a new `hashFunction` ( using random values of a and b) every time it is executed. `R` can be hardcoded to be the same.

The idea is to then use the resulting `hashFunction` to deterministically calculate hash of a number.

Comment: Have you checked out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363459/scala-return-reference-to-a-function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious way to do this will work fine:

```
val r = new SecureRandom()
val R = r.nextInt()

def buildHashFunction(): Int => Int = {      
  val a = r.nextInt()
  val b = r.nextInt()
  def hashFunction(x: Int) =
    ( a * x + b ) % R

  hashFunction
}
```